# WP query_posts() работает не корректно

Tags: wordpress

У меня есть такой код:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'          => 'portfolio',
    'paged'              => $paged,
    'orderby'            => $orderby,
    'order'              => $order,
    );

global $query_string;

//var_dump($args);

query_posts($args);
```

Раньше был еще фильтр по категории

```
'category'           => '22'
```

Сейчас я его убрал, но все равно выводятся записи только с этой категории. Что я сделал не так?

Comment: А почему вы считаете, что он работает некорректно? Что вы ожидаете получить?

Comment: ожидаю вывода всех постов с портфолио. их там около 20

Comment: >Что я сделал не так? 
использовал  `query_posts` см wpmag.ru/2014/query_posts-wordpress/

Comment: я правлю сайт, написал так не я. задача как раз стоит сделать вывод всех, а они не выводятся

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, фильтр по категории как не работал, так и не работает. Потому что нет такого параметра `category` в `query_posts`. Есть:

```
cat(число)
category_name(строка)
category__and(массив)
category__in(массив)
category__not_in (массив)
```

Во-вторых, использовать `query_posts()` может быть опасно. `query_posts()` предназначена для самого WordPress и должна использоваться для изменения основного цикла WordPress. Если нужно создать еще один цикл, то используйте `get_posts()` или `WP_Query`. Эти функции могут принимать те же параметры, что и `query_posts()`.

Основной запрос WordPress — это запрос, который выполняется до вывода какого-либо текста на страницу (на раннем этапе). Параметры такого запроса собирает сам WP опираясь на: запрошенный URL; настройки ЧПУ (постоянных ссылок) и др. Так WordPress определяет сколько записей показать на странице, записи из какой рубрики показывать и т.д.

А вторичный запрос - это тот, который создается пользователем (темой, плагином) и выполняется дополнительно к основному. Например: вывод в сайдбаре списка популярных записей, вывод комментируемых записей и т.п.

Так вот, если использовать `query_posts()` для создания вторичных запросов (циклов), то могут появится ошибки, из-за которых будет рушиться структура и тип страниц, так как повторный вызов `query_posts()` переписывает базовый запрос WP, на основе которого определяется тип текущей страницы (запись, рубрика), определяется сколько записей показывать на странице (пагинация) и многое другое.

[Источник.](https://wp-kama.ru/function/query_posts)

**ВЫВОД**

Используйте `get_posts()` или `WP_Query`.