# Как добавить новое условие в meta_query?

Tags: php, wordpress

Допустим, на странице построен цикл с помощью `query_posts()`.
Подскажите, как добавить новое условие в `meta_query`? Т.е. не изменить условие выборки из базы данных, а добавить.

Comment: Покажите массив аргументов для query_posts () и что надо добавить.

Comment: >Покажите массив аргументов для query_posts () и что надо добавить

Comment: нет массива аргументов для query_posts, т.к. этот массив формируется самим движком. А мне нужно добавить диапазон цен. Этот диапазон находится в переменных $min и $max

Comment: извиняюсь, если не понятно изложил вопрос. Но по идее в вопросе указано "добавить в meta_query"

Comment: уточню, добавить, значит добавить в уже существующий массив meta_query, сформированный wordpress, и теперь нужно добавить в этот массив новый массив новых условий. Допустим это нужно сделать на странице категорий

Comment: У вас есть некий код, где идет вызов. Вот от него и надо плясать, ответ зависит от того, что там уже в meta_query.

Comment: Кроме того, я так вижу, что это woocommerce, раз диапазон цен. Так?

Comment: Кроме того, рекомендую прочитать вот это http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/641428/220220 насчет query_posts

Comment: >Кроме того, я так вижу, что это woocommerce, раз диапазон цен. Так?

Comment: так, но это сейчас не так важно, без использования woocommerce также можно оперировать массивом meta_query

Comment: >Кроме того, рекомендую прочитать вот это

Comment: А при чём здесь ваша ссылка по основам использования query_posts ? Мне ведь как я говорил уже, не нужно изменять главный цикл, а просто добавить в этот цикл одно условие, чтобы не создавать новый произвольный цикл!

Comment: А как раз при том, что крайне не рекомендуется трогать главный цикл.

Comment: >А как раз при том, что крайне не рекомендуется трогать главный цикл

Comment: хорошо, не буду использовать этот главный цикл. Как тогда забрать все данные этого главного цикла, и передать эти все данные в произвольный цикл? + добавить диапазон цен.  Это нужно сделать на странице категорий

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться хуком `pre_get_posts`:

```
<?php
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'add_my_args');
function add_my_args($query) {
    if ($query->is_main_query()) { //если вмешаться нужно только в главный цикл
        $meta_query = array('key' => 'value');
        $query->set('meta_query', $meta_query);
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте примерно так.

```
$meta = array(
   'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
     'key' => 'my_price',
     'compare' => '<',
     'value' => $max
    ),
    array(
     'key' => 'my_price',
     'compare' => '>',
     'value' => $min
    )
);

set_query_var('meta_query', $meta);
```

Comment: а при чём здесь set_query_var до произвольного цикла? Вы ведь только что говорили, что нельзя менять главный цикл?

Comment: Ну что мне с вами делать, раз вы хотите в него влезть? А никакого иного кода не показываете. Вы хотите получить абсолютно общий ответ? Он известен: 42 )))

Comment: хорошо, благодарю очень, извиняюсь, что сразу не правильно задал вопрос. Мне просто нужно было узнать, как правильно добавлять новые условия

Comment: кстати такой вариант также работает `$args['meta_key'] = '_price';
                                            $args['meta_value'] = array($minPrice, $maxPrice);
                                            $args['meta_compare'] = 'BETWEEN'; query_posts( $args );` нашёл методом проб

Comment: Это то же самое, вид сбоку )

Comment: кстати в вашем коде есть `'key' => 'my_price'`, наверно правильней будет `'key' => '_price'`  для woocommerce?

Comment: Вы же хотели общий ответ, включая не только woocommerce, я потому так и написал )

Comment: KAGG Design, Ваш код не работает. Ну добавили дополнительное условие с помощью set_query_var. А как теперь обновить главный цикл с этим новым условием? Что нужно указывать в query_posts( ? );

Comment: А это потому, что ваш вопрос не соответствует правилам сообщества. Я не могу телепатически прочитать, куда вы запихиваете этот код. Почитайте вот это http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: >А это потому, что ваш вопрос не соответствует правилам сообщества.

Comment: извиняюсь, постараюсь в следующий раз понятней излагать суть вопроса. А что теперь, создавать новую тему?
Подскажите пожалуйста, как нужно сделать правильно?

Comment: ведь если меняется условие выборки в главном цикле, то ведь обязательно нужно вызывать query_posts чтобы обновить объект $wp_query. Разве это не очевидно? $wp_query ведь сам не обновится

Comment: и как я понял, ваш код перезаписывает meta_query, а нужно просто добавить в уже существующий meta_query